# VB.Net Updated All Data Not Selected Data

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
 Dim con As New MySqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand

    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=lamberto;User id =lamberto;password=rahasia"

    con.Open()

    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tbl_data_pegawai SET nip = @nip, nama_pegawai = @nama_pegawai, tempat_lahir = @tempat_lahir, tanggal_lahir = @tanggal_lahir, jenis_kelamin = @jenis_kelamin, usia = @usia, status_pegawai = @status_pegawai, tanggal_pengangkatan_cpns = @tanggal_pengangkatan_cpns, alamat = @alamat WHERE nip = + @nip"

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nip", TextBox1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nama_pegawai", TextBox2.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tempat_lahir", TextBox3.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tanggal_lahir", TextBox4.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jenis_kelamin", TextBox5.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usia", TextBox6.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status_pegawai", TextBox7.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tanggal_pengangkatan_cpns", TextBox8.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alamat", TextBox9.Text)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    con.Close()

    MsgBox("Data Updated")
```

This is my **update** code, but when I clicked the update, all data in my database update, not selected data. There is any solution ?

Comment: As an aside, i would not post my username+password in the internet.

Comment: that's not real username and password haha, I already change it

Answer (score 0):

You are setting nip to @nip Where nip = + @nip... remove the setting of nip... just set all other columns and remove the + in the WHERE section.

So you have:

```
UPDATE tbl_data_pegawai SET nama_pegawai = @nama_pegawai, tempat_lahir = @tempat_lahir,
tanggal_lahir = @tanggal_lahir, jenis_kelamin = @jenis_kelamin, usia = @usia, 
status_pegawai = @status_pegawai, tanggal_pengangkatan_cpns = @tanggal_pengangkatan_cpns, 
alamat = @alamat WHERE nip = @nip
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data? The script I will give you should only update rows where nip = the value you have in TextBox1